# recv() failed: Bad file descriptor c++ Linux

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, tcp

I have a problem. My program includes 10 TCP Server at the sam etime. As soon as a request from a client is noticed, the appropriate tcp server socket will accept the connection and handle it in a seperate thread. I know this is not the most efficient way of solving my actual problem but okay..

In main I have a for loop that will call a function in an object called Peer which is StartThread()

```
for (it= ListOfPeers.begin();it!= ListOfPeers.end();it++)
{
    (*it).second->StartThread();
}
```

Of cause there are some conditions that this loop will be used but i wanted to narrow the code as much down as possible.

The function StartThread will be called in each peer object:

```
    void StartThread()
{
    pthread_t threadDoEvent;
    pthread_create( &threadDoEvent, NULL, &DoEvent_helper,this);
    pthread_detach(threadDoEvent);
}

void *DoEvent_helper( void *ptr ) // Helper to implement thread
{
    return ((Peer *)ptr)->DoEvent();
}
```

DoEvent is the function which will handle the request and connection:

```
void* DoEvent()
{
    unsigned char  buffer[1024];
    int rc;
    int    close_conn= FALSE;
    int new_sd;

    new_sd = accept(Socket, NULL, NULL);
    if (new_sd < 0)
    {
        if (errno != EWOULDBLOCK)
        {
            perror("  accept() failed");
            close_conn = TRUE;
        }
    }


    do
    {
        rc = recv(new_sd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        if (rc < 0)
        {
            if (errno != EWOULDBLOCK)
            {
                perror("  recv() failed");
                close_conn = TRUE;
            }
            break;
        }

        if (rc == 0)
        {
            printf("  Connection closed\n");
            close_conn = TRUE;
            break;
        }

[DO SOMETHING WITH THE BUFFER]

        rc = send(new_sd, buffer, len, 0);
        if (rc <= 0)
        {
            perror("  send() failed");
            close_conn = TRUE;
            break;
        }
    }while (close_conn==FALSE);
     close(new_sd);
}
```

My Question is why am I receiving an error : recv() failed: Bad file descriptor????
When I am adding a sleep(1) in between pthread_create and pthread_detach, everything is working!
Can somebody explain this circumstances to me? or maybe help me solving my problem?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to return something from the `DoEvent` function, or you have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Well you *do* try to receive even if `accept` fails. This leads me to believe that you haven't properly set up the passive `Socket` file descriptor properly before trying to accept from it.

If you set up the `Socket` descriptor in the main thread, then it could be that the new thread starts and runs before you do that.

Comment: The passive socket is created whithin the constructor of each Peer, in fact constant. If accept fails should there be a perror("  accept() failed"); coming up? and what i forgot, was that a couple of times when i start the application it works but after a short while i receive this recv error

Comment: does it mean i should implement a condition for my do while ? something like if new_sd >0 ??

Answer (score 0):

Make sure new_sd is in persistent memory. e.g if it is allocated by a function that launches the thread and exits, then new_sd will be pointing to junk. (at least that was the case for me)