# Unable to receive data after connection getting Bad file Descriptor error

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, sockets

I am working on a Multi-threaded Server application in C using Pthreads(Linux).
My system is dual boot.Windows 7 as well as Ubuntu. I restarted my PC and booted into Windows from Ubuntu, Before restarting my server application was working Fine.After i again booted to ubuntu from windows. and started my server i start getting following Error when a client connects.

```
recv failed: Bad file descriptor
```

Here is My code:

Main.C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h> //for socket,AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM
#include <arpa/inet.h> //for sockaddr_in
#include <string.h>   //for memset()  
#include <pthread.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "extern.h" 

#define MAX_CONNECTIONS  5

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int sock_desc = 0, connfd = 0,listenfd =0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    int clntSock; 
    struct sockaddr_in echoClntAddr; 
    unsigned int clntLen; 
    char sendBuff[1025];
    char recvBuff[10025];
    int n = 0;
    pthread_t thr;



    sock_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 

    if(sock_desc < 0 )
       dieWithError("Unable to open Socket\n");  

    memset(&serv_addr,0,sizeof(serv_addr)); 

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET ;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(7024);

    if(bind(sock_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
       dieWithError("bind failed\n");

    if(listen(sock_desc,MAX_CONNECTIONS) < 0)
       dieWithError("listen failed\n");  

     file = fopen("testServer.txt", "w");

      clntSock = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
      int i =0;
      fcntl(sock_desc, F_SETFL, fcntl(sock_desc, F_GETFL, 0) | O_NONBLOCK);

      while(1)
    {

        connfd = accept(sock_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&echoClntAddr,(socklen_t*)&clntSock);

      if(connfd > 0){  
         puts("Connection accepted");

        if( pthread_create( &thr, NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) &connfd) < 0)
        {
            perror("could not create thread");
            return 1;
        }

        puts("Handler assigned");
        }    
    }

    if (connfd < 0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }


       return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void dieWithError(char *errormsg){
     printf("%s", errormsg);  
}
```

HandleConnection.c

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include "extern.h"



void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
{

    int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
    t_data.t_id = sock;

    int read_size;
    char *message , client_message[2000];

    while( (read_size = recv(sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)) > 0 )
    {

       client_message[read_size] = '\0';
           t_data.msg = client_message; 


           printf("%s",client_message); 

        memset(client_message, 0, 2000);
    }

    if(read_size == 0)
    {
        puts("Client disconnected");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    else if(read_size == -1)
    {
        perror("recv failed");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I tried by restarting my PC but same problem persists.Please Help.

Comment: Seems to be duplicated. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758307/recv-failed-bad-file-descriptor-c-linux

Comment: @DamiánMontenegro: The cause why `recv()` fails is the same, the reason why `recv()` receives the `-1` in this question however is much more subtile then in the question you linked, where is's just a dump bug, a missing return, break, whatever, which is not the case here. So I object your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(The issue you observe has nothing to do with running on a dual-boot machine.)

The code as shown introduces a race by using the address of the same variable for each incoming connection to pass the socket descriptor to the thread function.

The race occures if `accept()` would return faster a second time. To fast for the thread-handler to store what the address it got passed pointed to via executing:

```
int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
```

In your specfic case with the listening socket set to non-blocking this most likley is the case, when only one connection came in, the handler got the address of `connfd` passed in and in parallel `accept()` gets called again on the (non-blocking) listening socket, no incoming connection is waiting and `accept()` returns immediately and sets `connfd` to -1. This happens faster then the handler for the previous connection could have called

```
int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
```

and with this store the `-1`.

To observer this effect (**not to fix the issue**) modify your code as follows:

```
int result = accept(sock_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&echoClntAddr, &clntSock);
if (0 > result)
{
  perror("accept() failed");
}
else
{
  connfd = result;

  puts("Connection accepted");

  if( pthread_create( &thr, NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) &connfd) < 0)
  {
    ...
```

The handler then would begin like this:

```
    void *connection_handler(void * pv)
    {
      int sock = *((int*) pv);
      fprintf("sock = %d\n", sock);
      ...
```

To fix your issue there are two approaches:

1. Misuse the thread-function's  `void*` argument to pass an `int`.

   ```
   socklen_t clntSock = ...;
   ...
   connfd = accept(sock_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&echoClntAddr, &clntSock);

   if (0 <= connfd)
   {
     if (pthread_create( &thr, NULL, connection_handler, (void *) connfd) < 0)
     {
       ...
   ```

   The handler then would begin like this:

   ```
   void *connection_handler(void * pv)
   {
     int sock = (int) pv;

     ...
   ```

   This is a common, but somewhat "hacky" solution, which relies on a pointer being at least as wide as an `int`.
2. Use a seperate instance of an `int` to store the result of `accept()`.

   ```
   socklen_t clntSock = ...;
   ...
   connfd = accept(sock_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&echoClntAddr, &clntSock);
   if (0 <= connfd)
   {
     int * pconnfd = malloc(sizeof *pconnfd);
     if (NULL == pconnfd)
       ... // fail and leave here
     *pconnfd = connfd;
     if (pthread_create(&thr, NULL, connection_handler, pconnfd) < 0)
     {
       ...
   ```

   The handler then would begin like this:

   ```
   void *connection_handler(void * pv)
   {
     int connfd = *((int *) pv);
     free(pv);

     ...
   ```

   This is a clean and portable approach, with the cost of an additional pair of calls to `malloc()`/`free()`.

Other corrections in the code shown above:

- Define the variable whichs address is passed to `accept()` to be `socklen_t` as the 3rd parameter to `accept()` is defined as `socklen_t *`. If passing a pointer to something else and this "something" is of different size than `socklen_t` `accept()` would run into undefined behaviour.
- Test the outcome of `accept()` against `<0` for error as `0` is a valid value for a file/socket descriptor.

Comment: HI if i comment  fcntl(sock_desc, F_SETFL, fcntl(sock_desc, F_GETFL, 0) | O_NONBLOCK); line everything works fine.

Comment: @Simer: See my updated answer. For a blocking socket (the default) `accept()` would block if no other incoming connection is pending, so `connfd` wouldn't get overwritten. If however two connection would arrive at the time. The value returned by `accept()` for the 2nd connection might get stored for the 1st. A bug much more difficult to identify as such, as `recv()` for the 1st handler would not fail but simply read from the 2nd connection as well. Ugly.

Comment: To explicitly state this again: Using your code as shown *and* commenting out the call setting the listening socket to `non-blocking` **does not** fix the bug. It **just hides** it until the servers receives many requests in a short time.

Comment: Hi I changed  int sock = *(int*)socket_desc; to following and it is working fine. 
    int sock = (int) socket_desc;

Is it Ok now.

Comment: @Simer: I updated my answer commenting on both proposed solution's "cleanliness".

Comment: @Simer: Also you might want take into account my "other" proposals on modifications/corrections to your code.

Comment: what is pi in (sizeof *pi)

Comment: @Simer: This has been a typo which is fixed now.

Comment: Hi can u do me one more favor plz . Here is a link can u plz answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30725206/multithreaded-server-in-linux

Comment: are u considering answering the Question in above link??

Comment: @Simer: I'd consider it as answered.

Comment: Has the answer provided to it  Perfect.??

Comment: Hi sir can u plz answer this question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30885668/exiting-a-thread-after-communication-process-is-over?noredirect=1#comment49811363_30885668