# Exiting a Thread after Communication Process is Over

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I am working on a Multi threaded server application in C using Pthreads.How can i exit a thread and free the resources being used by it after the client sends a request for closing the connection. I am pasting my code below

Main.C

```
#include "extern.h" 

int thread_counter = 0;
int rc;

void main(int argc, char** argv){

    int sock_desc = 0, connfd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    int clntSock; 
    struct sockaddr_in echoClntAddr; 
    int n = 0;   

   pthread_t thr;

    sock_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 

    if(sock_desc < 0 )
       dieWithError("Unable to open Socket\n");

    fcntl(sock_desc, F_SETFL, fcntl(sock_desc, F_GETFL, 0) | O_NONBLOCK); 

    memset(&serv_addr,0,sizeof(serv_addr)); 

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET ;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(7024);

    if(bind(sock_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
       dieWithError("bind failed\n");


    if(listen(sock_desc,MAX_CONNECTIONS) < 0)
       dieWithError("listen failed\n");  

       clntSock = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
       int i =0;

    while(1){

         connfd = accept(sock_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&echoClntAddr,(socklen_t*)&clntSock);


         if(connfd > 0){  
            puts("Connection accepted");

            if(pthread_create( &thr, NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*)connfd) < 0){
               perror("could not create thread");
            }

            puts("Handler assigned");

        }    
    }

}

    void dieWithError(char *errormsg){ 
         printf("%s", errormsg);    
    }
```

HandleConnection.C

```
#include "extern.h"

void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc){
    int sock = (int) socket_desc;
    int read_size;  
    char client_message[2000];
    int i;
    int rc = 5;



    while(1){
        read_size = recv(sock , client_message , 2000 , 0); 
        if(read_size > 0){

       client_message[read_size] = '\0';
        printf("%s",client_message); 

        }

        memset(client_message, 0, 2000);


    if(read_size == 0){
       puts("Client disconnected");
     pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);
    pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS,NULL);
       fflush(stdout);
      rc = close(sock);

       break;
    }
    else if(read_size == -1){
            perror("received failed");
            break;
    }

} 

}
```

How and where should i write a routine to exit a Thread after its work is Over.i tried using pthreads_cancel  but it didn't helped,reason might be i haven't used it properly.

Comment: Just return from the thread function? You either need a way to signal the main thread about it so it can join the thread, or create a detached thread.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg sir can u plz provide a sample example in answer. Actually i am totally a beginner in Linux and server multithreading and not having much knowledge about Pthreads.

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is.Can you post your thread function and how you create threads and explain how it doesn't work as you expected?

Comment: @BlueMoon I have pasted the complete code above. I just want to know that how can i close a thread when it is no longer required. I want to do it in HandleConnection.C under "client disconnected".

Comment: @Eljay While `pthread_cancel()` can do the same job, you `pthread_exit()` is much simpler and appropriate for your situation. What happens if you simply call `pthread_exit(NULL);`? Also, you can make a thread detach itself by simply calling `pthread_detach(pthread_self());`.

Comment: @BlueMoon pthread_detach(pthread_self()) will close the current thread and free the resources used by it ??

Comment: @Eljay It won't "close" the thread. It'll just make sure the thread resources are cleanup once it exits. So when you call `pthread_exit`, all the resources the thread was holding would be freed.

Comment: What happens if `recv()` fills the whole 2000 byte buffer? It seems to me that `client_message[read_size] = '\0';` will write out-of-bounds in that case.

Comment: 'memset(client_message, 0, 2000);' - why?